# Raising a float to a very large number Python (matrix powers) with modulo (knowing that end product is an integer)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math

I'm trying to find the power of a 2x2 integer matrix M^n. This can be done to a very high power (e10000 for example). Normally, I would be taking the modulo of a max size matrix directly, which could take O(N) time with numpy.linalg.matrix_power or some trickery could give you O(logN) time.

But matrix diagonalization shouldn't be too hard to theoretically turn this into an O(1) problem which could speed this problem up pretty significantly. Conceptually this should be pretty easy by just getting the power of 2 constant numbers. However, when the integer is diagonalized, the two constants are irrational numbers.

So, I go into an overflow state when trying to get the power of the diagonal matrix. Knowing that the final result will be some very large integer that I need to take a modulo of, I'm trying to figure out a good way to take the power of this irrational number.

Is there any way to do this in a way quicker than just multiplying the 2x2 matrix by itself?

Comment: To actually do this with floating-point, I think you'd need a variable-precision floating-point arithmetic library and an amount of precision scaling with N, so it wouldn't be constant time anyway.

Comment: I think you need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Can you provide a real-world example of input matrix and modulus? With integers like only 2, the result can be `>=2**10000` which is a huge number. It is certainly a good idea to apply the modulus iteratively during the computation to make it much faster. Computing number `>=2**64` is significantly slower because modern CPUs are designed to only work on <= 64-bit integers. Operation on larger integers require many additional operations so they are significantly slower to compute (they are *not* computed in `O(1)` time here)

Comment: @JérômeRichard this was based on a problem where you have a m x n matrix (n is given) with y possible values in each point, and you want to find the number of possible matrix combinations there are if you input m (you're given n and y) with the condition that ys can't be directly adjacent.